# Sharepoint 2010 workflows

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, designer-workflow

I do not know a great deal about approval workflows but here is my predicament. I need a three step process. How do I get a **completed workflow** to **trigger** another **workflow**? This is a cut down of my process below:

**Step 1:**
Manager agrees to supporting an application
Supported | Not Supported
When this workflow has finished it needs to trigger the next workflow

**Step 2:**
Director Approval
Approve | Reject
When this workflow has finished it needs to trigger the next workflow

**Step 3:**
CEO Endorsement
Endorsed | Rejected

Answer (score 0):

With a 2010 workflow you can do this with multiple workflows. Before starting the workflow you will need to add an extra column to to fill when workflow 1 is completed. It can be a fill in or drop down column. At the end of the first workflow you can use the "set" command to set that column to say something like "completed."

With the second workflow, the start option should allow the workflow to be started when an item is changed (instead of when it is created, or manually). Then, for step 1 of the second workflow use an if statement to say "if" that workflow1 column is set as completed, then ____ and enter the rest of what you would like to do.

Repeat the above step of adding that extra column, but with a new column, for this workflow as well.

Comment: Brilliant. Love Thanks for the swift response. I'll try it out and get back to you.

Comment: Am I able to use this all in the one workflow - separating it into steps?

Comment: Something appears to be missing. 
I have created a new column as suggested and set the value to completed at the end of my first workflow.
Preceding this a checkbox in the form which initiates the 1st workflow.
then start the approval process on the current item.
I feel as though the status of the workflow needs to be captured before setting the workflow 1 text value.
This I don't know how to do.

Comment: Hi -- I am not quite sure I understand what you mean. Perhaps you can upload a picture? I'd recommend doing this in multiple workflows, so you can kickoff the first workflow with the check box, and then set the status of that workflow as completed at the end of the first workflow. The second workflow should be set to start when an item is changed, to kickoff that workflow when that status box is changed.

Comment: Thanks everyone - I have it sorted. I have posted a solution which worked for me as part of a similar issue.